# rotation issue in ios 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, rotation, orientation

I've looked everywhere, Yet I cant find a solution for this annoying rotation issue in iOS 6.

for some reason, I cant get the rotation methods in iOS 6 to work. they are not even called.

for example:

if I want to keep a view in portrait mode in iOS 5, I use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);    
}
```

I learned that the new method in iOS 6 should be:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I've also try to add:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

but it dosent work at all.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have all that it should be as simple as setting the supported orientations in the Info.plist as well as in your controllers. You can do this through the Summary tab on your project target.